# Elasticsearch aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, facet, drilldown

I'm trying to build category drilldown with elasticsearch.

I've problem with showing category counts.

If I run this query (Red, casual pants) , category aggregations will show up only casual's count.
Can i retrieve other categories count in a single query (such as shoes,jeans,dresses)

Example Filters:

Colors:

> -Red Color (selected as a bool query term)

Categories:

```
Shoes
Pants
    -Jeans
    - Casual (selected as a bool query term)
Dresses
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you seem to need to calculate your aggregations on all categories, and then filter it to show only one categorie at a time.

This can be achieved using `post_filter` (see [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html#search-request-post-filter)). It's a filter which is applied **after** the aggregations have been computed.

In your case, instead of querying like this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term": {"color": "red"} },
        {"term": {"category": "casual"}}
        ....
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    ...
  }
}
```

You use this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term": {"color": "red"} }
        ...
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    ...
  },
  "post_filter": {
    {"term": {"category": "casual"}}
  }
}
```

And the `term` filter on `category` won't be taken into account when computing the aggregations.